# WordPress jSON API how to return data with jquery?

Tags: json

I enabled json API successfully in a WordPress blog but I have hard time returning data with jQuery.

http://example.com/?json=1&count=1&include=title

Here is the json format. Ideally I'd like to append in a div called #homeblog, the last post title, linked to the post itself.

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 1,
  "count_total": 1,
  "pages": 1,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "post",
      "slug": "hello-world",
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/?p=1",
      "title": "Hello world!",
      "title_plain": "Hello world!",
      "content": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!<\/p>\n",
      "excerpt": "Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!\n",
      "date": "2009-11-11 12:50:19",
      "modified": "2009-11-11 12:50:19",
      "categories": [],
      "tags": [],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
      },
      "comments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Mr WordPress",
          "url": "http:\/\/wordpress.org\/",
          "date": "2009-11-11 12:50:19",
          "content": "<p>Hi, this is a comment.<br \/>To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.<\/p>\n",
          "parent": 0
        }
      ],
      "comment_count": 1,
      "comment_status": "open"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append some data returned by the JSON api to a page you would need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://example.com/?json=1&count=1",function(data) {
        $('body').append('<a href="'+data.posts[0].url+'"><div id="homeblog">'+data.posts[0].title+'</div></a>');
    }
```

I have removed the `include=title` part of the json call because that excludes everything else. You are using `getJSON` to return the post `data`, then it is just a case of constructing your html and `append` ing it to the page somewhere (in my case right onto the `<body>` tag)

EDIT: there is a [wordpress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for wordpress questions. you will have more luck asking questions like this over there.

(added a right bracket)